# Implications from the form of Binnet equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

[Binnet equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation),
$$\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}\left(\frac{1}{r}\right)+\frac 1r=-\frac{m}{L^2}F(r)r^2,$$
where $m$ and $L^2$ are positive constants, can be used to give the orbit $r(\theta)$ of a particle in a central force field. The condition $L^2\neq 0$ implies that the orbit is a strictly increasing function.

Let $r_1$ be a maximum or a minimum value of $r(\theta)$ such that $r(\theta_1)=r_1$. This point, $(r_1,\theta_1)$, is called an [apsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsis). Then I read the following sentence from a book:

> From Binnet equation's form it follows that the orbit is symmetric in
> $\theta$ about the segment $OA_1$ going from the origin to the apsis
> $A_1$.

I understand the meaning of this sentence but I don't understand why it is true. What specifically in Binnet equation leads to this symmetry about $OA_1$? I see that Binnet equation is invariant under $\theta\rightarrow -\theta$ and $\theta\rightarrow \theta+\theta_0$. I still don't see how these could explain the sentence above. I would appreciate very much a non mathematicians' answer.

Comment: I think you have the answer at your fingertips: if the angle $\theta=0$ is defined to be at the turning point (ie at $OA_{1}$) then your observation about the $\theta\rightarrow -\theta$ invariance implies the $\theta$-symmetry about $OA_{1}$.

Comment: @AloneAndConfused But the symmetry about $OA_1$ should be independent of the definition of angle's origin. What I understand from $\theta\rightarrow -\theta$ symmetry is that there are equally good solutions for $\theta$ evolving in any direction (the particle's orbit can have any orientation).

Answer (score 2):

I think I got the answer.

Binet equation is invariant under $\theta\rightarrow -\theta$. But only by defining $\theta=0$ at a turning point $A_1=(r_1,\theta_1=0)$ the solution can be reflected about the segments $OA_1$. This is so because the initial conditions
$$r(\theta_1=0)=r_1,\quad r'(\theta_1=0)=0,$$
are also invariant under the transformation. The corresponding about any other segment $OA$, which is not an apsis, will not happen in general, because
$$r'(\theta=0)=v_\theta\neq 0,$$
may not be invariant. Thanks for @AloneAndConfused for pointing out that the answer was indeed int the reflection symmetry of the equation.